# Inputs to UA-Model Compiler (OPCUA)

Tags: opc-ua

Based on the Github page of [UAModelCompiler](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-ModelCompiler), the docker container used for UA Model Compiler requires two inputs.

1. xml file
2. csv file

Although the XML file can easily be generated using UaModeler, I am not sure how to generate the CSV file for the same XML.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'Export NodeIds' function next to the 'Export XML' in UaModeler.

Comment: Any suggestion how this can be done when creating an Information Model in SioME (Siemens OPCUA modelling editor) ??    The application only has "export XML" function

Answer (score 0):

The CSV file is not an input but an output. It can be generated by the Model Compiler with `-cg` option.

See https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-ModelCompiler/blob/master/README.md